# What's wrong with this Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have written an ajax call from a function to be triggered on clicking on an image. At the php page the image is rotated using php gd. Somehow the ajax is not being triggered. I am unable to figure out where I am doing the mistake!

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#rotate-head-1").click(function(){
            alert("Function running");

            var filename = document.getElementById('image-1').getAttribute('src');
            $.ajax({
                url:"test.php",
                type:"GET",
                async:true,
                data:{procedure:"rotate",file_name:filename},
                cache:false
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Success");
                }
                error: function() {
                    alert("Failure");
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<img id="rotate-head-1" src="rotate_icon.jpg" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt="Rotate Image" title="Rotate Image">
<img id="image-1" src="../../member_media/media/test.jpeg" width="200" border="0">
```

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: So is the whole click handler not getting triggered? Or is it just the ajax call?

Comment: When I remove everything in $.ajax({.. , then the "function running" alert is working. But when I put this, nothing is working (including that alert).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I spot on the eye is a missing comma after your `cache` and `success` options. Those errors should come up in the console, you can use that to debug these kind of issues on the fly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rotate-head-1").click(function(){
        alert("Function running");

        var filename = document.getElementById('image-1').getAttribute('src');
        $.ajax({
            url:"test.php",
            type:"GET",
            async:true,
            data:{procedure:"rotate",file_name:filename},
            cache:false //<-- you miss a comma here?
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Success");
            } // <-- and miss a comma here
            error: function() {
                alert("Failure");
            }
        });

    });
});
```